# Changing dropdown options ipywidgets based on previous selection in Python

Tags: python, plot, dropdown, ipywidgets

I have my code laid out as follows in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
# Ask user for the Site they would like to view data for
Site = input("Enter the Site number that you would like to see data for: ")
# Choose the dataset based on the user input
if Site == '1':
    df = site1_df
else:
    df = site2_df
```

And in the following cell I have an interactive plotting cell using `ipywidgets` as follows:

```
@interact
def line_plot(Variable=list(df.select_dtypes('number').columns),
              time=widgets.ToggleButtons(options=['Raw', 'Minute', 'Hour', 'Day', 'Month'], 
                                                    description='Time'),
              color_button=widgets.ToggleButtons(options=['polar', 'solar', 'henanigans'], 
                                                    description='Plot Theme'),
              color_scale=widgets.ToggleButtons(options=['spectral', 'pastel1', 'polar', 'dark2'], 
                                                    description='Colour Scale')):


    # The following resamples the data based on the user selection
    if time == 'Raw':
        new_df = df.resample('30S').mean()
    elif time == 'Minute':
        new_df = df.resample('T').mean()
    elif time == 'Hour':
        new_df = df.resample('H').mean()
    elif time == 'Day':
        new_df = df.resample('D').mean()
    else:
        new_df = df.resample('M').mean()

    # The newly resampled data is then plotted based on the users choice
    new_df.iplot(kind='line', y=Variable, xTitle='Time', yTitle='Test',
                 mode='lines', theme=color_button, colorscale=color_scale)
```

There are other elements of optimisation that I have to do, but I would like to have the `Site` selection as a dropdown menu like the others in the attached screenshot. But I can not seem to integrate it whereby the option selected for the `Site`, changes the `Variables` that are displayed. I have seen some other posts on this but can't seem to integrate it for my situation. Any help welcomed!

[image: Screenshot of Notebook dashboard]

Comment: Can you mock up some data for site1 and site2 in code by creating some random data?

Comment: Hey @ac24, it is a simple 1-d df with timeseries data (5s) with power data in the columns

Comment: If you can create some dummy examples like this `df = pd.DataFrame({"foo_id": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})` it will make it easier to assist.